# Node Formidable Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, formidable

I am struggling to identify which radio button is ticked using formidable in Node. Here is my form:

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <div class="form-group text-center">
     <div class="radio">
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="clean" checked="checked">Clean</label>
     </div>
     <div class="radio">
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="clean">Waste</label>
     </div>
     <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" accept=".xlsx">
     <input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload">
   </div>
 </form>
```

When I parse using `form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {}` fields only contains `{"clean":"on"}` regardless of which radio button is checked at the time of posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `value` attribute in your radio buttons, for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="clean" value="clean" checked>
<input type="radio" name="clean" value="waste">
```

When the `value` attribute is not specified, it defaults to `"on"`, which is exactly what you're observing.